# Compare ajax variable with php variable symfony 2

Tags: php, ajax, forms, symfony

I would like to compare a selected date on my datepicker with the actual date in my controller for this I use ajax to send the selected date:

```js
$('.datepicker').datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
    firstDay: 1,
    minDate:0,
    beforeShowDay: DisableTuesday,
    onSelect: function(e) {
        var date= $("input").val();
        $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                data: date,
                async: false
            })
    }
});
```

```html
        if ( $request->isMethod( 'POST' )) {

            $date= ($request->getContent('date'));
            $date= new Response($date, 200);
            if ((date('d-m-Y') == $date)) {
                return $date;

            }
            else {
                some stuff
            }
```

Problem is the variable I get is not comparable with (date('d-m-Y') Anyone knows How can I do it ?

Do I need to convert it to string ?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: after `var_dump()` die;?

Comment: Sorry but what do you mean ?

Comment: `var_dump($request->query->all()); die;`

Comment: Thx but No changes

Comment: `dump($request->query->get('request'));die;` ?

Answer (score 0):

Probably you want to access `quantity` value that you are passing under `data` key. You could use `POST` method instead of `GET`. It'll send this data in request body instead of query parameters so in you PHP code instead of:

```
var_dump($request->query->all());
```

you should write:

```
var_dump($request->getContent());
```

Comment: Now my var_dump display : " string(0) ""  "  instead of " NULL "

It's a little bit better :)

Comment: It looks more like problem with Javascript code that makes a request instead of request handling in PHP. You could check in e.g. chrome dev tools or symfony profiler what is this ajax request URL and body.

Answer (score 0):

If you use jQuery do something like this

```
<div class="well">
   <select id="quantity" class="dropdown">
     <option value="1">test1</option>
     <option value="2">test2</option>
     <option value="3">test3</option>
   </select>
   <button id="btn-quantity">OK</button>
</div>

$('#btn-quantity').click(function(){
    var quantity = $('#quantity').val();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "{{ path('louvre_pages_homepage') }}",
        data: {
           qty: quantity
        }
    });
});
```

> https://jsfiddle.net/dfm0nnq8/

Note that it is preferable that you use [POST](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#page-54) and not [GET](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#page-53).

**Please read the documentation of previous links**

Get your quantity in your controller like this

```
public function formAction(Request $request)
{
    if ($request->isMethod('POST')) {
        $qty = $request->get('qty');
    }

    return $this->render('LouvrePagesBundle:Pages:index.html.twig');


}
```